# extract words from string python and add them in array using nlp

Tags: python, nlp

I have this problem in Python. I will import a line like say "Mary has a little lamp." I need to implement NLP so that I can put each word into an array.
So the output will be a[0] = 'Mary' and so on.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
i = 0 
mytext = "Hello Mr. Adam, how are you? I hope everything is going well. Today is a good day, see you dude."
blah = [word_tokenize(i) for i in mytext]
blah[1]
```

The output gives 'e'

Comment: Have you tried with string methods? Such as `str.split`?

Comment: no need of loop. use word_tokenize(i)

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
blah = word_tokenize(mytext)
```